# Not able to pull data from Census API because it is rejecting calls

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to run this script to extract data from the US census but the census API is rejecting my request.  It is rejecting my pulls, I did a bit of work, but am stumped....any ideas on how to deal with this

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from pandas.compat import StringIO
#Sourced from the following site https://github.com/mortada/fredapi
from fredapi import Fred
fred = Fred(api_key='xxxx')
import StringIO
import datetime
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO as stio
else:
    from io import StringIO as stio
year_list = '2013','2014','2015','2016','2017'
month_list = '01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'
#############################################
#Get the total exports from the United States
#############################################
exports = pd.DataFrame()

for i in year_list:
    for s in month_list:
        try:
           link="https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/intltrade/exports/hs?get=CTY_CODE,CTY_NAME,ALL_VAL_MO,ALL_VAL_YR&time="
            str1 = ''.join([i])
            txt = '-'
            str2 = ''.join([s])
            total_link=link+str1+txt+str2
            r = requests.get(total_link, headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'})
            df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(r.text))
            ##################### change starts here #####################
            ##################### since it is a dataframe itself, so the method to create a dataframe from a list won't work ########################
            # Drop the total sales line
            df.drop(df.index[0])
            # Rename Column name
            df.columns=['CTY_CODE','CTY_NAME','EXPORT MTH','EXPORT YR','time','UN']
            # Change the ["1234" to 1234
            df['CTY_CODE']=df['CTY_CODE'].str[2:-1]
            # Change the 2017-01] to 2017-01
            df['time']=df['time'].str[:-1]
            ##################### change ends here #####################            
            exports = exports.append(df, ignore_index=False)
        except:
            print i
            print s
```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then repost your question. If we cant copy/paste your code into our IDE or run it easily, we cant help debug the problem. Also attach your stack trace / error to the question

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import ast
import itertools

import pandas as pd
import requests

base = "https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/intltrade/exports/hs?get=CTY_CODE,CTY_NAME,ALL_VAL_MO,ALL_VAL_YR&time="
year_list = ['2013','2014','2015','2016','2017']
month_list = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']

exports = []
rejects = []

for year, month in itertools.product(year_list, month_list):
    url = '%s%s-%s' % (base, year, month)
    r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'})
    if r.text:
        r = ast.literal_eval(r.text)
        df = pd.DataFrame(r[2:], columns=r[0])
        exports.append(df)
    else:
        rejects.append((int(year), int(month)))

exports = pd.concat(exports).reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
```

Your result looks like this:

```
      CTY_CODE             CTY_NAME   ALL_VAL_MO    ALL_VAL_YR     time
0         1010            GREENLAND       233446        233446  2013-01
1         1220               CANADA  23170845914   23170845914  2013-01
2         2010               MEXICO  17902453702   17902453702  2013-01
3         2050            GUATEMALA    425978783     425978783  2013-01
4         2080               BELIZE     17795867      17795867  2013-01
5         2110          EL SALVADOR    207606613     207606613  2013-01
6         2150             HONDURAS    429806151     429806151  2013-01
7         2190            NICARAGUA     75752432      75752432  2013-01
8         2230           COSTA RICA    598484187     598484187  2013-01
9         2250               PANAMA   1046236431    1046236431  2013-01
10        2320              BERMUDA     47156737      47156737  2013-01
11        2360              BAHAMAS    256292297     256292297  2013-01
       ...                  ...          ...           ...      ...
13883     0024                LAFTA  27790655209  193139639307  2017-07
13884     0025            EURO AREA  15994685459  121039479852  2017-07
13885     0026                 APEC  76654291110  550552655105  2017-07
13886     0027                ASEAN   6030380132   44558200533  2017-07
13887     0028                 CACM   2133048149   13333440411  2017-07
13888     1XXX        NORTH AMERICA  41622877949  299981278306  2017-07
13889     2XXX      CENTRAL AMERICA   4697852283   30756310800  2017-07
13890     3XXX        SOUTH AMERICA   8117215081   55039567414  2017-07
13891     4XXX               EUROPE  25201247938  189925038230  2017-07
13892     5XXX                 ASIA  38329181070  274304503490  2017-07
13893     6XXX  AUSTRALIA AND OC...   2389798925   16656777753  2017-07
13894     7XXX               AFRICA   1809443365   13022520158  2017-07
```

Walkthrough:

- `itertools.product` iterates over the product of (year, month) combinations, joining them with your `base` url
- if the text of the response object is not blank (periods such as 2017-12 will be blank), create a DataFrame out of the literally-evaluated text, which is a list of lists.  Use the first element as columns and ignore the second element.
- otherwise, add the (year, month) combo to `rejects`, a list of tuples of the items not found
- I used `exports = []` because it is much more efficiently to concatenate a list of DataFrames than to append to an existing DataFrame